# Another bug in g++/Clang? [C++ Templates are fun]

Tags: c++, templates

Check out the following code (written just for fun)

```
namespace N
{
   template<typename T>
   struct K
   {

   };
}
template<typename T>
struct X
{
   typename T::template K<T> *p; //should give error 
                                 //N::K<int> has no template member named `K`
};

int main()
{
   X<N::K<int> > l;
}
```

The code gets compiled on g++(4.5.1) and Clang whereas Comeau and Intel C++ give (similar) errors.

The errors that I get on Comeau are :

```
"ComeauTest.c", line 13: error: class "N::K<int>" has no member "K"
     typename T::template K<T> *p;
                          ^
          detected during instantiation of class "X<T> [with T=N::K<int>]" at
                    line 18

"ComeauTest.c", line 13: error: expected an identifier
     typename T::template K<T> *p;
                           ^
          detected during instantiation of class "X<T> [with T=N::K<int>]" at
                    line 18
```

So my question is "Is the code sample ill-formed ?" According to me "Yes". Does that mean this is yet another bug in g++/Clang?

Comment: How is this "not a real question"? What's wrong with you guys?

Comment: Whoever voted to close this as "not a real question" needs to stop trying to grok C++ templates and get back to their Java IDE. _Since when is_ __Is this a bug in my compiler?__ _not a real question?_

Answer (score 50, accepted):

### Why GCC and Clang think they are right

`K`, which is the injected class name, has a dual nature in the scope of `K<int>`. You can use it without template arguments. Then it refers to `K<int>` (to its own type).

It can be followed by a template argument list too. IMO it's reasonable to say that you need to prefix it with `template` because of the parser ambiguity with the `<` that follows. It then refers to the specified type that's determined by the template arguments.

So it can be treated as a member template and as a nested type, depending on whether it's followed by a template argument list. Of course, `K` is not really a member template. The dual nature of the injected class name seems to me more of a hack anyway, though.

The Standard has an example that reads like this:

```
template <class T> struct Base { };
template <class T> struct Derived: Base<int>, Base<char> {
   typename Derived::Base b; // error: ambiguous
   typename Derived::Base<double> d; // OK
};
```

One might be inclined to conclude from this that the intent is that you could leave off the `template`. The Standard says

> For a template-name to be explicitly qualified by the template arguments, the name must be known to refer to a template.

I can't see how this wouldn't apply to `T::K<T>`. If `T` is a dependent type then you can just lean back because you can't know what `K` refers to when parsing it, so to make any sense of the code, you just have to be able to prefix it with `template`. Notice that n3225 has that example too, but it's not a defect there: You can officially leave off `template` if you lookup into the template's own scope in C++0x (it's called the "current instantiation").

So until now, Clang and GCC are fine.

---

### Why Comeau is right

Just to make it even more complicated, we will have to consider the constructors of `K<int>`. There is a default constructor and a copy constructor implicitly declared. A name `K<int>::K` will refer to the constructor(s) of `K<int>` *unless* the name lookup used will ignore function (constructor) names. Will `typename T::K` ignore function names? 3.4.4/3 says about elaborated type specifiers, which `typename ...` is one of:

> If the name is a qualified-id, the name is looked up according its qualifications, as described in 3.4.3, but ignoring any non-type names that have been declared.

However, a `typename ...` uses different lookup. 14.6/4 says

> The usual qualified name lookup (3.4.3) is used to find the qualified-id even in the presence of typename.

The usual qualified lookup of 3.4.3 won't ignore non-type names, as illustrated by the example attached to 14.6/4. So, we will find the constructor(s) as specified by 3.4.3.1/1a (the additional twist that this only happens when non-types are *not* ignored was added by a later defect report, which all popular C++03 compilers implement though):

> If the nested-name-specifier nominates a class C, and the name specified after the nested-name-specifier, when looked up in C, is the injected-class-name of C (clause 9), the name is instead considered to name the constructor of class C. Such a constructor name shall be used only in the declarator-id of a constructor definition that appears outside of the class definition.

So in the end, I think comeau is correct to diagnose this, because you try to put a template argument list onto a non-template and also violate the requirement quoted in the last part (you use the name elsewhere).

Let's change it by accessing the injected name by a *derived* class, so no constructor name translation occurs, and you *really* access the type so that you *really* can append the template arguments:

```
// just replace struct X with this:
template<typename T>
struct X
{
   struct Derived : T { };
   typename Derived::template K<T> *p;
};
```

Everything compiles now with comeau too! Notice I already did problem report to clang about this exact thing. See [Incorrect constructor name resolution](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=8263). BTW, if you declare a default constructor in `K`, you can see comeau give a better error message if you use `T::K<int>`

```
"ComeauTest.c", line 13: error: overloaded function "N::K<T>::K [with T=int]" is
          not a template
     typename T::template K<T> *p;
```

Comment: AWESOME explanation! nothing more can be said!