# No class template named X in templated class

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, crtp

When tryin to compile this (CRTP-like) code with GCC 4.6.0:

```
template<template<class> class T> struct A;

template<class T> 
struct B: A<B<T>::template X> {
    template <class U> struct X { U mem; };
};

B<int> a;
```

I get the errormessage "test.cpp:3:26: error: no class template named ‘X’ in ‘struct B<int>’". Why does X seem to be invisible outside the class definition?

Comment: My compiler has a problem with this: : A< B<T>::template X>   The X is an undeclared identifier.  I'm frankly confused by your syntax, what's B<T>::template supposed to be? Besides I've never seen: template<class> class T.  If anything, I think I'm going to learn something from you; can you please explain the importance of the syntax, what these do?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe Johannes's answer from this topic might help here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420828/another-bug-in-g-clang-c-templates-are-fun

Comment: @leetNightshade: I'm not sure but I think you're error message is actually saying the same thing as mine: that X is not visible outside B (this is how I understand it anyway). About your second question: "template<class> class T" means that T is templated itself. Like that you can use something like T<double> inside the class definition of A.

Comment: What are you trying to do...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Emile Cormier correctly points out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794347/no-class-template-named-x-in-templated-class/5794508#5794508) the problem is that at the place of instantiation of `A`, `B` is still an incomplete type, and you cannot use the inner template.

The solution for that is moving the template `X` outside of the template `B`. If it is independent of the particular instantiation  `T` of the template `B`, just move it to the namespace level, if it is dependent on the instantiation, you can use type traits:

```
template <typename T>
struct inner_template 
{
   template <typename U> class tmpl { U mem; }; // can specialize for particular T's
};
template <typename T>
struct B : A< inner_template<T>::template tmpl >
{
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`struct B` is still considered an incomplete type when you specify `A<B<T>::template X>` as the base class.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use a member of `B` as a parent of `B` creating a recursive-esque situation. For example this doesn't compile either:

```
template<template<class> class T> struct A {};

struct B : public A<B::nested>
{
        struct nested {};
};
```

Comment: That's not true: I'm passing B as a template parameter, I'm not inheriting from it.

Comment: @Tom De Caluwé I changed my answer to show that even as a template parameter it's still treated as an incomplete type which can't be used as a template parameter.