# Simulating templated constructor. Too odd?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I wanted to make a templated constructor, but I found I had no way of explicitly listing the template arguments, so I had to find another solution. Here's what I did:

```
ResourceManager rm = ResourceManager::Create<physfs::ifstream>();
```

Do you have any other ideas how I might achieve this upon construction? or is this a good enough solution (not too odd)?

Note: I'm using a move constructor (which is the only public constructor) to avoid creating unnecessary copies of the class.

Comment: The answer to [this question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230448/is-it-possible-to-have-a-templated-constructor-like-templateclass-t-x) should also answer your question. (Can't delete the comment because the mobile view of SO won't let me...)

Comment: @Xeo Yes, I know of that limitation. I was wondering what workarounds there are.

Comment: I've seen this before.  The only way to bypass it that I know of is to pass an instance of the templated type to thee constructor, so the compiler automatically deduces the type.  Or use a std::constant_integer<Num> for template parameters.

Comment: @Mooing I've never seen `std::constant_integer` before. What header is it from? (Googling didn't turn out anything useful.)

Comment: It's actually `integral_constant`. I'm not sure where it is officially stored, but `type_traits` works for me. It's a TR1 addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code should do. To improve design, consider declaring types inside (for instance) ResourceManager and using that to qualify the constructors, as needed.