# C++ confusing attribute name for member template

Tags: c++, templates

I've found that when accessing a non-template attribute (`v.foo`) from a variable of a template type (`T& v`), C++ can be tricked into thinking that it is a member template if there is a template function of the same name (`template class <T> void foo()`). How can this be explained from the C++ spec? Consider this simple program:

```
#include <cassert>

/** Determine whether the 'foo' attribute of an object is negative. */
template <class T>
bool foo_negative(T& v)
{
    return v.foo < 0;
}

struct X
{
    int foo;
};

int main()
{
    X x;
    x.foo = 5;
    assert(!foo_negative(x));
    return 0;
}
```

We have a template function `foo_negative` that takes an object of any type and determines whether its foo attribute is negative. The `main` function instantiates `foo_negative` with [T = X]. This program compiles and runs without any output.

Now, add this function to the top of the program:

```
template <class T>
void foo()
{
}
```

Compiling it with G++ 4.6.3 results in this compiler error:

```
funcs.cpp: In function ‘bool foo_negative(T&)’:
funcs.cpp:13:14: error: parse error in template argument list
funcs.cpp: In function ‘bool foo_negative(T&) [with T = X]’:
funcs.cpp:25:5:   instantiated from here
funcs.cpp:13:14: error: ‘foo’ is not a member template function
```

(Where Line 13 is `return v.foo < 0` and Line 25 is `assert(!foo_negative(x))`.)

Clang produces similar errors.

Wat? How did adding an unrelated function that is never called manage to introduce a syntax error into a valid program? When parsing `foo_negative`, the compiler doesn't know the type of `v`, and crucially, it doesn't know whether `v.foo` is a member template or a regular member. Apparently, it has to decide at parsing time (before the template is instantiated) whether to treat it as a member template or a regular member.

If it thinks `v.foo` is a member template, then `< 0` is seen as passing `0` as a template argument, and there is a missing `>`, hence the syntax error. Then, when `foo_negative` is instantiated with [T = X], there is another error because `X::foo` is not a member template.

But why does it think `v.foo` is a member template? This ambiguity is precisely what the `template` keyword is for: if I wrote `v.template foo`, then I would be explicitly telling C++ to expect a member template, but I didn't use the `template` keyword! I didn't refer to a member template, so it should assume that it's a regular member. The fact that there's a *function* of the same name as the member shouldn't have any effect. Why does it? It can't be a bug in the compiler because GCC and clang are consistent.

Comment: That's weird. It compiles on gcc-4.3.4: http://ideone.com/FP3SO

Comment: No, you forgot to add the `template <class T> void foo()` declaration: http://ideone.com/FxEBm It doesn't compile.

Comment: perhaps it is really a bug in both gcc and clang: [declaration](http://ideone.com/zofCF). I changed `v.foo < 0` to `0 > v.foo` and it compiles fine. Maybe both compilers think `< 0` is template argument, as you mentioned in the question.

Comment: @user2k5 I don't think it's that simple. The specification _does_ special-case the less-than sign with respect to templates. If you don't see a less-than sign, it isn't ambiguous. It's only when you have a `<` that there is ambiguity. I'm just confused as to why the ambiguity is resolved differently depending on whether there is a separate template function.

Comment: Do you get the same problem, if you surround `v.foo` with parentheses? I.e. `return (v.foo) < 0;`

Comment: @bitmask Good question. In that case, it works: http://ideone.com/5fzqw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Clang, this was [PR11856](http://llvm.org/PR11856), which was fixed ~2.5 months ago. Clang trunk and Clang 3.1 do not report any errors with [this code](http://codepad.org/CLhyD4tr). The Clang bug includes an [explanation](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=11856#c2) of why this code was being rejected, and why the code is correct, reproduced here (slightly tweaked to address your case):

> The paragraph that matters here is **[basic.lookup.classref]p1**:
>
> "In a class member access expression (5.2.5), if the `.` or `->` token is
>   immediately followed by an *identifier* followed by a `<`, the identifier
>   must be looked up to determine whether the `<` is the beginning of a
>   template argument list (14.2) or a less-than operator. The identifier
>   is first looked up in the class of the object expression. If the
>   identifier is not found, it is then looked up in the context of the
>   entire *postfix-expression* and shall name a class template."
>
> Since `v` is dependent, presumably the *identifier* is not found so we
>   consider what happens if we look in the context of the entire
>   *postfix-expression*. Since we find a function template, we should not
>   conclude that we have the start of a *template-id*.

Comment: Thanks. I just found the [corresponding bug report in GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10200) that was reported in 2003, not yet fixed.

Answer (score 6):

It does look like a compiler bug.

The standard says:

> After name lookup (3.4) finds that a name is a template-name or that
>   an operator-function-id or a literal-operator-id refers to a set of
>   overloaded functions any member of which is a function template if
>   this is followed by a <, the < is always taken as the delimiter of a
>   template-argument-list and never as the less-than operator.

and in 3.4.5/1

> In a class member access expression (5.2.5), if the . or -> token is
>   immediately followed by an identifier followed by a <, the identifier
>   must be looked up to determine whether the < is the beginning of a
>   template argument list (14.2) or a less-than operator. The identifier
>   is first looked up in the class of the object expression. If the
>   identifier is not found, it is then looked up in the context of the
>   entire postfix-expression and shall name a class template.

The standard doesn't seem to indicate that the name lookup can ever find a non-member function template here. In any case, the meaning of `<` should be decided at template definition time, not instantiation time (it's too late then).

Answer (score 5):

**This is a bug.**

Your code is running fine on MSVC (2011).
I think the parser of the compiler translated the '<' as a start token for a template statement. But why Clang and GCC have this bug on the sametime?

Please report the bug [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/) and [here](http://llvm.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=clang).

Maybe this is also interesting:
[Another bug in g++/Clang? [C++ Templates are fun]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420828/another-bug-in-g-clang-c-templates-are-fun)

Comment: Are you sure it's a bug in GCC/Clang and not in MSVC? If you want to show that it's a bug, you have to show it from the specification, not from another implementation. Especially a Microsoft one -- they have a history of allowing things to compile that strictly shouldn't. I've skimmed the spec but it's pretty hard to make sense of (I'll read some more later) -- I'm betting that it's more likely there's some twisty clause in the spec (possibly §14.2.3) that G++ and Clang are following to the letter and MSVC is ignoring, but it could be the opposite.

Comment: And I will definitely file a bug if it can be shown that they violate the spec. It's just that in my experience, if you think there's a bug in the compiler, it's usually either a) your code, or b) you aren't reading the spec closely enough.

Comment: maybe... but the c++ specification is huge and it is very complicated. I know that MSVC is not the best compiler who is C++ specification conform, but I think the best thing to do now is to report the bug... maybe it is or it is not a bug...

Comment: FWIW, the Comeau online compiler also fails to compile with a similar error.

Comment: also the [Codepad](http://codepad.org/) online compiler fails with this error: In function 'bool foo_negative(T&)':
Line 12: error: parse error in template argument list
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors. [Code](http://codepad.org/CLhyD4tr)