# "end" cannot use in template function

Tags: c++, templates

I want to use a simple struct with member variables named `start` and `end` in a function template:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct st {
    int start;
    int end;
};

template<typename T>
void compare(const T& v1, const T& v2){
    if(v1.end < v2.end)
        cout << "v1 < v2" << endl;
}

int main() {
    st a = {1, 2};
    st b = {2, 3};
    compare(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

But this program fails to compile on mingw g++ 4.8.2 with:

```
main.cpp: In function 'void compare(const T&, const T&)':
main.cpp:11:11: error: parse error in template argument list
     if(v1.end < v2.end)
           ^
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'void compare(const T&, const T&) [with T = st]':
main.cpp:18:17:   required from here
main.cpp:11:5: error: 'end' is not a member template function
     if(v1.end < v2.end)
     ^
```

Why not? What's wrong with my code?

Comment: what's the exact error message? BTW, Test type is not defined anywhere.

Comment: 1.The line "Test test" should delete and I forget. I want to a mini code to read. 2. the error message is :  test.cpp: In member function 'void compare(const T&, const T&)':
test.cpp:14:15: error: parse error in template argument list
         if(v1.end < v2.end)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is clearly a gcc bug (specifically [10200](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10200) although there are several dupes with lots of different examples). [temp.names] states:

> When the name of a member template specialization appears after . or -> in a *postfix-expression* or after a
>   *nested-name-specifier* in a *qualified-id*, and the object expression of the *postfix-expression* is *type-dependent*
>   or the *nested-name-specifier* in the *qualified-id refers* to a dependent type, but the name is not a member of
>   the current instantiation (14.6.2.1), the member template name must be prefixed by the keyword `template`.
>   **Otherwise the name is assumed to name a non-template.** *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> struct X {
>     template<std::size_t> X* alloc();
>     template<std::size_t> static X* adjust();
> };
>
> template<class T> void f(T* p) {
>     T* p1 = p->alloc<200>();          // ill-formed: < means less than
>     T* p2 = p->template alloc<200>(); // OK: < starts template argument list
>     T::adjust<100>();                 // ill-formed: < means less than
>     T::template adjust<100>();        // OK: < starts template argument list
> }
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*

`v1` and `v2` are *type-dependent*, so the name should be assumed to name a non-template due to the omitted `template` keyword and the `<` should be treated as less than, exactly as in the example above.

Not to mention that [basic.lookup.classref] states that:

> The identifier is first looked up in the class of the object
>   expression. If the identifier is not found, it is then looked up in the context of the entire *postfix-expression* and shall name a class template.

And `end` should clearly be found in the class of the object expression - it's a simple member variable, after all. The fact that it's a failure for `end` only because of the collision with `std::end()` further supports the idea of bug since that scope should never have been considered to begin with.

Amusingly, the simplest solution is simply: [don't use `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)!

Answer (score 8):

Actually it's the `<` which confuse the compiler, since it does not know whether it's the start of a template expression, or the comparator.

Since @R Sahu asked for an official sources, here is the explanation :

> The paragraph that matters here is [basic.lookup.classref]p1:
>
> "In a class member access expression (5.2.5), if the `.` or `->` token is
>   immediately followed by an identifier followed by a <, the identifier
>   must be looked up to determine whether the < is the beginning of a
>   template argument list (14.2) or a less-than operator. The identifier
>   is first looked up in the class of the object expression. If the
>   identifier is not found, it is then looked up in the context of the
>   entire postfix-expression and shall name a class template."
>
> Since v is dependent, presumably the identifier is not found so we
>   consider what happens if we look in the context of the entire
>   postfix-expression. Since we find a function template, we should not
>   conclude that we have the start of a template-id.

Source : [C++ confusing attribute name for member template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671406/c-confusing-attribute-name-for-member-template)

And here is the corresponding `gcc` bug : https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10200

> *** Paolo Carlini 2015-06-23 15:03:03 UTC ***
>
> Bug 65878 has been marked as a duplicate of this bug.
>
> *** Colin MacKenzie 2015-06-23 22:19:29 UTC ***
>
> Had this one today. Strange that it compiles fine in 4.4.6 but not in
>   4.8.2.

```
error: parse error in template argument list 
Ex: assert(block.begin <  block.end);

works when I parenthesize the block.begin 
Ex. assert( (block.begin) < block.end);
```

> *** Paolo Carlini 2015-06-23 22:21:28 UTC ***
>
> This should be fixed ASAP, but I'm not actively working on it at the
>   moment.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that g++ 4.8.4 also has problems when the member variable is `begin` or `end`.

Using

```
struct st{
    int begin;
    int end;
};

template <typename T>
void compare(const T& v1, const T& v2){
    if(v1.begin < v2.begin)
    {
        cout << "v1.begin < v2.begin" << endl;
    }
    if(v1.end < v2.end)
    {
        cout << "v1.end < v2.end" << endl;
    }
}
```

produces the following error message for me.

```
socc.cc: In function ‘void compare(const T&, const T&)’:
socc.cc:12:11: error: parse error in template argument list
     if(v1.begin < v2.begin)
           ^
socc.cc:16:11: error: parse error in template argument list
     if(v1.end < v2.end)
           ^
socc.cc: In instantiation of ‘void compare(const T&, const T&) [with T = st]’:
socc.cc:25:17:   required from here
socc.cc:12:5: error: ‘begin’ is not a member template function
     if(v1.begin < v2.begin)
     ^
socc.cc:16:5: error: ‘end’ is not a member template function
     if(v1.end < v2.end)
```

Perhaps someone more familiar with g++ development than me can provide more details.

One work around is to use avoid using `begin` and `end` as member variables.

```
struct st{
    int _begin;
    int _end;
};
```

or

```
struct st{
    int _start;
    int _end;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, for the time being you can check the condition in reverse order.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct st {
    int start;
    int end;
};

template<typename T>
void compare(const T& v1, const T& v2){
    if(v2.end > v1.end)    //changed the comparison order
        cout << "v1 < v2" << endl;
}

int main() {
    st a = {1, 2};
    st b = {2, 3};
    compare(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```